# Sockets won't reconnect to namespaces/reregister handlers on server

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am assigning sockets to namespaces on my server similar to this:

```
let io = require('socket.io')(port, options)
io.of('/webClient').on('connection', socket => {
  socket.on('someEvent', () => console.log('do things!'));
});
```

However, when my clients reconnect for any reason, they are not getting to `'do things!'` For example, when I take down my socket server, my clients try to reconnect automatically. However, when they reconnect, they are being re-added to the namespace and proper rooms, however their handlers aren't being assigned because `'connection'` event isn't firing.

Thinking that my clients were maintaining some sort of state that was stopping these events from being emitted, I tried manually reconnecting on the clients using `socket.close()`, but the same problem is still occurring on reconnection.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? If my socket server goes down, I need these event handlers to be re-run on returning sockets so I can respond to events on them. But if I don't have a handle to them in the namespace, then how to I catch them and identify them?

Comment: The code in your question has me confused.  `let io = io(url);` is client-side code.  But, `io.of('/webClient').on('connection', ...)` looks like server-side code.  Can you clear up what code is where?

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks for pointing that out! I fixed up the creation line. :)

Comment: I cannot reproduce what you describe.  When I have a client that connects on a namespace and then I take the server down and bring the server back up, I see the client reconnect on the namespace just fine.  There must be something else going on here.  Also, what version of socket.io are you running?